# Select single row based on multiple criteria in same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

It's very difficult to describe what I want with words so here are the tables I'm dealing with

```
Persons
First | Last  | ID
John  | Smith |  1
Jane  | Smith |  2

PerKey
ID |  KW  | HITS
1  | P.E. |  1
1  | M E  |  1
1  | HVAC |  4
2  | Acct |  7
```

What I want to do is select from persons where criteria meets multiple rows.

For instance I would like to know who has a 'P.E.' AND 'M E' AND 'HVAC'.

In this case that would return John Smith.

I have been able to accomplish this with the IN and HAVING clauses, but that limits me to not being able to filter how many times an individual has that KW and OR clauses.

Say I only wanted someone with 5 hits on 'HVAC', that would rule John Smith out ideally.  Here's the query I have atm:

```
 SELECT first, last 
 FROM persons 
 LEFT JOIN perkey ON persons.id = perkey.id
 WHERE kw IN ('P.E.','M E','HVAC')
 GROUP BY first, last, persons.id
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT kw) = 3
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008.  I cannot change the data structure either as it's proprietary.  Thanks for any help/advice.

Comment: Each 'id' has a single row for each 'kw' and the 'hits' column is what I want to filter off of. i.e. I want someone with HVAC 'kw' and >5 in the 'hits' column. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *conditional aggregation* in order to selectively count each of the possible `kw` values:

```
 SELECT first, last,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN kw = 'P.E.' THEN 1 END) AS PE,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN kw = 'M E' THEN 1 END) AS ME,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN kw = 'HVAC' THEN 1 END) AS HVAC
 FROM persons 
 LEFT JOIN perkey ON persons.id = perkey.id
 WHERE kw IN ('P.E.','M E','HVAC')
 GROUP BY first, last, persons.id
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT kw) = 3
```

**Edit:**

If you want to filter records based on, say, `HVAC` occurrences, then you can add the conditional aggregate in `HAVING` clause, e.g.:

```
 SELECT first, last            
 FROM persons 
 LEFT JOIN perkey ON persons.id = perkey.id
 WHERE kw IN ('P.E.','M E','HVAC')
 GROUP BY first, last, persons.id
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT kw) = 3 AND 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN kw = 'HVAC' THEN 1 END) > 5
```

**Edit2:**

If you want to filter records based on the value of `hits` field, then you can use:

```
 SELECT first, last            
 FROM persons 
 LEFT JOIN perkey ON persons.id = perkey.id
 WHERE kw IN ('P.E.','M E','HVAC')
 GROUP BY first, last, persons.id
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT kw) = 3 AND 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN hits > 4 THEN 1 END) > 0
```

Comment: Syntax is incorrect, can you switch the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Thanks for the remark. I just copy/pasted the query from the OP.

Comment: This is counting occurrences as in if that 'id' and 'kw' was repeated several times in the table (correct me if I'm wrong); however, the table is not set up that way.  Each 'id' has a single row for each 'kw' and the 'hits' column is what I want to filter off of.  i.e. I want someone with HVAC 'kw' and >5 in the 'hits' column.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Conditional grouping should work, both to check for all types of kw, and to limit or further inspect the # of occurrences of any/all types. Like this:

```
SELECT persons.id, first, last,
    SUM(CASE WHEN kw = 'P.E.' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN kw = 'M E' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ME,
    SUM(CASE WHEN kw = 'HVAC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HVAC
FROM persons 
LEFT JOIN perkey ON persons.id = perkey.id
WHERE kw IN ('P.E.','M E','HVAC')
GROUP BY first, last, persons.id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN kw = 'P.E.' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 
AND SUM(CASE WHEN kw = 'M E' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 
AND SUM(CASE WHEN kw = 'HVAC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Comment: HVAC conditional aggregation should be = 5 based on OP's statement "Say I only wanted someone with 5 hits on 'HVAC'"

Comment: Yes, but that was just an example ("say i wanted...") of what I took to be the general case.  It's not a big stretch to see that it is applicable for that specific case.